# Elastic Beanstalk failed to unzip source file with UTF-8 file name

Tags: deployment, utf-8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, unzip

I was trying to deploy a NextJS application to Elastic Beanstalk via `eb deploy`. But the source bundle failed to unzip during deployment as the source bundle contained some pre-built .next page which the file name is in UTF-8 encoding. The error is stated as below.

```
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.xxxxxx [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2022/xx/xx xx:xx:xx.xxxxxx [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2022/01/31 04:56:44.300483 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2022/01/31 04:56:45.932820 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: Command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/ failed with error exit status 50. Stderr:error:  cannot create /var/app/staging/.next/server/pages/\u6e2c\u8a66/\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66.html
        File name too long
error:  cannot create /var/app/staging/.next/server/pages/\u6e2c\u8a66/\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66\u6e2c\u8a66.json
        File name too long
```

I was able to unzip the file with option `-O UTF-8`, is there any way I could add this flag to the `eb deploy` unzip process?

edit 1. I am working with the Platform `64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.4.9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is good practice, but I eventually added an ebextensions to overcome the original unzipping flow.

```
commands:
  command backup original zip: 
    command: |
      logger "backup zip" && cp /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle /tmp/app_source_bundle_bak &&
      logger "rm existing zip .next folder" && zip -Ad /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle ".next/*"
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
    ignoreErrors: false

container_commands:
  replace the original zip to staging: 
    command: |
      logger "custom unzip" &&
      unzip -O UTF-8 -q -o /tmp/app_source_bundle_bak -d /var/app/staging/
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
    ignoreErrors: false
```